# accessing props().x returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using the create-react-app typescript starter and I noticed props are not working. Am I doing something wrong?

```
import * as enzyme from "enzyme";
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "./Box";

describe("Box component", () => {
  let wrapper: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = enzyme.shallow(<Box x={0} y={2} />);
  });

  it("should not render without x", () => {
    expect(wrapper.props().x).toBe(0);
  });
});
```

And this is the error I'm getting.

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected value to be:
      0
    Received:
      undefined

    Difference:
```

Comment: Have you tried `wrapper.instance().props` or `enzyme.mount(...)` ?

Comment: @AlexandreAnnic thank you, just tried and got this error:     TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null

Comment: @AlexandreAnnic huh, it seems to only work when mount() ??

Comment: Enzyme is also a mystery for me :-). Maybe check that https://gist.github.com/fokusferit/e4558d384e4e9cab95d04e5f35d4f913

Answer (score 0):

```
it("should not render without x", () => {
    expect(wrapper.prop('x')).toBe(0);
  });
```

Use prop() instead of props()